Helper class ContentBlockHelper
enter image description here
When I m trying to run CakePHP based application I'm getting following error:
Helper class ContentBlockHelper could not be found.
It occurred when I copied CakePHP application to production server. Just mentioned PHP version on server is 5.3.10.

That's an extremely old version of PHP. What version of CakePHP are you using? What was your process for "copied CakePHP application to production server"?
